# I am getting Local Variable i Referenced before assignment error even though i have assigned it at very first line of code

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
i=1
def abc(): 
    a=str(l2.get())
    l1.insert(i,a)
    i=i+1        
w=Tk()
w.geometry("500x300")
l1=Listbox(w,height=3)
l2=Entry(w)
l3=Button(w, text='insert', command=abc)
l1.grid(row=1,column=1)
l2.grid(row=2,column=1)
l3.grid(row=3,column=1)
w.mainloop()
```

## I am getting UnBoundLocalError: Local variable 'i' refrenced before assigmnent

Comment: You need to add `global i` at the beginning of `abc()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks your answer was correct my code is finally working even my teacher at my college couldn't understand the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, to access `global` variable and make an assigment with that global reference inside the function, you need first declare it as `global` inside function block. But, if you use `global`, every assignment you make inside `function` block will affect `i` in `global` scope too!

This not the end of the world if that's expected. But if you want to maintain `global` scope variable, then you can try the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

i=1

def abc():
  import __main__
  j = __main__.i
  a=str(l2.get())
  l1.insert(j,a)
  j = j+1
  print(j)                  #tracking

w=Tk()
w.geometry("500x300")
l1=Listbox(w,height=3)
l2=Entry(w)
l3=Button(w, text='insert', command=abc)
l1.grid(row=1,column=1)
l2.grid(row=2,column=1)
l3.grid(row=3,column=1)
w.mainloop()
print(i)                    #tracking
```

Result after a single click on `insert` then exit immediately:

```
2
1
[Finished in 2.5s]
```

Comment: Thanks you Solved my doubt.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to acw1668
he has answered in comment "You need to add global i at the beginning of abc(). – acw1668 1 min ago"
I have tried now its working now.
I wanted to mark his answer as correct but since he added in comment I cannot mark it as correct. Declaring in global environment already means it global as much as my teacher taught me in College I don't know why then I had to reference it is global separately in function.

Comment: If `i` is not modified inside `abc()`, then `global i` is not necessary.  But since `i` is modified in `abc()`, then the interpreter will treat it as a local variable.  So you need to tell the interpreter that `i` is a global variable.